# Limit of a boundary of increasing sequence of sets

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Let $U$ be a bounded open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Suppose the sets $V_m$ are an increasing sequence of closed sets such that $V_{m}\subset V_{m+1}$ and that $\cup_{n=1}^\infty V_n=U$. Then does it hold that $d_H(\partial\cup_{n=1}^k V_n,\partial U)\to0$ as $k\to \infty$, where $d_H$ is the Hausdorff distance and $\partial$ denotes the boundary of a set.

I am relatively certain I have managed to prove this in the case where the sets $V_k$ are dyadic cubes but my proof is long and cluncky. I was wondering if I could relax the conditions a bit and so obtain a shorter proof. So does the above hold in general?

Comment: By $\lim V_k$ do you mean $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty V_k$?  Just asking.

Comment: $\cup_{k=1}^{\infty}V_k$, pardon me

Comment: I think this is true in any metric space if $\bar U$ is compact.  It can fail for unbounded $U$. For example $U=\Bbb R\times \Bbb R^+$ and $V_n =([-n,n]\times [1/n,\infty))\cup (\Bbb R\times [1,\infty)$